# PowerBI incremental update - Change of structure

Tags: powerbi, office365, ssas, tabular-editor

In a Premium Workspace in Power BI O365, I have set-up a dataset with incremental update on a table `T1`.

When I need to change a formatting settings of something similar on `T1`, or make chanegs on other tables than `T1`, I use ALM Toolkit To update dataset ; it is working.

However, I have an issue when I want to add a new column on the table `T1`. I would like to keep all the data already retrieved in O365 and simply use the new column for the future sync ; but each time I try to do that, data is no longer available.

I see in SSMS, connected to the O365 Power BI Analysis Service, that the partitions in the table are replaced by only one partition with a default name.

Resync from the O365 Power Bi website is not possible because of the size of the DataSet ; I need to recreate the partitions with Tabular Editor and after that to resync the partitions one by one.

I have to mention that I am not a data analyst, and I only know a few things on how it behaves. I have seen there's some options in the Partition processing in SSMS and ALM Toolkit (Recalc, Default, Full, Do nothing) ; but I was not able to achieve my goal when changing this parameter.

Does anyone knows how to do what I want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the ALM Toolkit, under Options there is setting `For table updates, retain partitions`. See if you have that enabled. See this video for an example of adding and deploying a calculated column: https://youtu.be/s0j6d3UAw9U?feature=shared&t=356

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how I missed it. I was looking only at the Processing Option...